# Training SVM model with GridSearchCV runs forever

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I got my hands on a dataset with customers and I am trying to calculate the churn rate. I already did it with Logistic Regression and now I want to use SVC with GridSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning. I did that already with my logistic regression model, but when I try the same in SVC my laptop is on fire and doesn't finish for hours. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = dict(C=[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
                  class_weight=["balanced", "none"]
                  kernel=["linear"])

svm=SVC()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm,
                    param_grid=param_grid,
                    scoring='f1'
                    verbose=3,
                    n_jobs=-1)

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

At `grid.fit` the script run forever... I tried to reduce the amount of parameters in `param_grid` with no luck. Any help?

Comment: data is still unknown here, I feel that data need to be looked upon if there is room for feature selection or scaling of the data. hard to tell without knowing X_train and y_train

Comment: Welcome to SO; please be as consise as possible and avoid introductions and other conversational stuff irrelevant to the specific issue at hand (edited).

Comment: I have already done scaling, feature selection, I've checked the correlations within the dataset and I have removed features that correlate with each other ... can I provide you with any more information to help you understand the problem?